# JQuery Validation not working on master page in asp .net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some .aspx pages with one master pages. I want to give client side validation to all controls on the .aspx pages. For this i am using jquery validation.(ketchup plugins of validation by ashley on papermashup.com tutorials)

It works properly on .aspx page "Without" master page.
But when am using same code & link files on master page then it is not working.

Code without master page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="validation_demo.aspx.cs" Inherits="webpages_validation_demo" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/jquery.ketchup.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.messages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.validations.basic.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../Styles/favicon.ico" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <link href="../CSS/jquery.ketchup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="../CSS/style_menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../CSS/Form_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="../CSS/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../image/jquery.js"></script> 
    <link href="../CSS/modalbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Js/CommonFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Js/CommonValidations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#signup').ketchup();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" runat="server" method="post" id="signup">
    <div style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:50px;">
          <input type="text" class="validate(required ,number, minlength(10) ,maxlength(10))"  name="number" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code with master page:

master page:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master_demo.master.cs" Inherits="webpages_Master_demo" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/jquery.ketchup.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.messages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.validations.basic.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../Styles/favicon.ico" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <link href="../CSS/jquery.ketchup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="../CSS/style_menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../CSS/Form_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <link href="../CSS/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../../image/jquery.js"></script> 
        <link href="../CSS/modalbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="../Js/CommonFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Js/CommonValidations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#signup').ketchup();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <form action="" runat="server" method="post" id="signup">   
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>  
</form> 
    </body>
    </html>

aspx pge with master page:

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/webpages/Master_demo.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="demo_validation1.aspx.cs" Inherits="webpages_demo_validation1" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#signup').ketchup();
        });
    </script>
    <div style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:50px;">
              <input type="text" class="validate(required ,number, minlength(10) ,maxlength(10))"  name="number" /> 
     </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the form element on your masterpage with the ID of signup

-- Update

OK

Change your input to the following

```
 <input type="text" data-validate="validate(required ,number, minlength(10) ,maxlength(10))"  name="number" />
```

Redownload the ketchup plugin here

https://github.com/mustardamus/ketchup-plugin/downloads

and use the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ketchup.all.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.messages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ketchup.validations.basic.js"></script>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Make sure the css references are pointing to the correct paths

Comment: yeah it is proper but i am using data-validate="validate(required)" istead of Class="validate(required)"

Comment: Check the documentation at http://mustardamus.com/new-ketchup/docs/index.html for how to apply styles using  ketchup